# Magento 2.1.4 product import failure

Tags: magento2

First I export my product in a csv file and then i try to reimport but during check magento fail with general exception.Someone can help me about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, I've found the "General Exception" notice to be caused by either an error occurring too many times during the import, or due to a field being supplied with data that it is not compatible with (effectively breaking form validation).

In order to troubleshoot this on my end, I started ruling out fields by attempting an import with single line item on my local environment, where I was able to trash the DB and reset to a pre-import state without any risk to production data.  I was also able to gain some insight by viewing Magento's exception and debug logs on the command line (under /var/log).  In my case, "General Exception" was being caused by too many products having a combination of a category path that was too long, and having unsupported characters in the product name.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew Sanjanwala  i tested the import using category path less longer and the check work correctly.